# Transition between two UINavigationControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uinavigationcontroller, core-animation

- I have 2 UINavigationControllers.
- Both are added ([window addSubview:]) to the window as subviews.
- One of them has its alpha set to 0.0
- The other has its alpha set to 1.0

My question is: Given my current design, is it possible to transition (ex: page flip) between the two nav controllers?

Side note: The reason I have them both added at all times is because otherwise they can't handle the Orientation changes properly. Only the one in the View hierarchy handles orientation changes. But that is another story.

Thank you,
Vance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than considering them as two navigation controllers, you should be thinking of it as flipping the views provided by them. While I haven't tested this, I expect this to do the trick –

```
[UIView transitionFromView:firstNavController.view 
                    toView:secondNavController.view 
                  duration:2.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews|UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^{
                    self.window.rootViewController = secondNavController; // If you have set the `rootViewController` property
                }];
```